Was Eleazar ben Dama related to Dama ben Netina?
Kiddushin 31a records the story of a non-Jew named Dama ben Netina. The story of Eleazar ben Dama is recorded in a few places (Tosefta Chullin 2:22,23; Avodah Zarah 27b; Yerushalmi Avoda Zarah 2, 40d).
The latter seems to be the nephew of Yishmael ben Elisha.
Based on the name I would like to know if any source identifies Eleazar ben Dama as the son of Dama ben Netina
